# objective-c memory management--how long is object guaranteed to exist?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting

I have ARC code of the following form:

`NSMutableData* someData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:123];`
...

`CTRunGetGlyphs(run, CGRangeMake(0, 0), someData.mutableBytes);`
...

`const CGGlyph *glyphs = [someData mutableBytes];`
...

...followed by code that reads memory from `glyphs` but does nothing with `someData`, which isn't referenced anymore.  Note that CGGlyph is not an object type but an unsigned integer.

Do I have to worry that the memory in `someData` might get freed before I am done with `glyphs` (which is actually just pointing inside`someData`)?

All this code is WITHIN the same scope (i.e., a single selector), and `glyphs` and `someData` both fall out of scope at the same time.

PS In an earlier draft of this question I referred to 'garbage collection', which didn't really apply to my project.  That's why some answers below give it equal treatment with what happens under ARC.

Comment: Are you _actually_ running with GC enabled? You have to go out of your way to turn it on, and it's (pre-)deprecated. Or are you talking about ARC, which is not GC?

Comment: Josh asks a good question. GC != ARC.

Comment: @JoshCaswell it's more than pre-deprecated, it's fully and officially deprecated. See the very bottom of the FAQ at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17

Comment: Thanks, @Tommy. I hadn't seen that note, and I couldn't remember whether Lion had deprecated it or not, so I was being conservative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of summer 2012, things are in the process of change for Apple objects that return inner pointers of non-object type.  In the [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/Foundation.html) for Mountain Lion, Apple says:

> NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER
>
> Methods which return pointers (other than Objective C object type)
>   have been decorated with the clang compiler attribute
>   objc_returns_inner_pointer (when compiling with clang) to prevent the
>   compiler from aggressively releasing the receiver expression of those
>   messages, which no longer appear to be referenced, while the returned
>   pointer may still be in use.

Inspection of the NSData.h header file shows that this also applies from iOS 6 onward.

Also note that `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER` is defined as `__attribute__((objc_returns_inner_pointer))` in the [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) specification, which makes it such that

> the object's lifetime will be extended until at least the earliest of:
>   the last use of the returned pointer, or any pointer derived from it,
>   in the calling function; 
>   or the autorelease pool is restored to a
>   previous state.

Caveats:
If you're using anything older then Mountain Lion or iOS 6 you will still need to use any of the methods discussed here (e.g., `__attribute__((objc_precise_lifetime))`) when declaring your local NSData or NSMutableData objects.

Also, even with the newest compiler and Apple libraries, if you use older or third party libraries with objects that do not decorate their inner-pointer-returning methods with `__attribute__((objc_returns_inner_pointer))` you will need to decorate your local variables declarations of such objects with `__attribute__((objc_precise_lifetime))` or use one of the other methods discussed in the answers.

Answer (score 4):

You are *potentially* in trouble whether you use GC or, as others have recommended instead, ARC. What you are dealing with is an *internal pointer* which is not considered an *owning reference* in either GC or ARC in general - unless the implementation has special-cased `NSData`. Without that owning reference either GC or ARC might remove the object. The problem you face is peculiar to internal pointers.

As you describe your situation the safest thing to do is to hang onto the real reference. You could do this by assigning the `NSData` reference to either an instance variable or a `static` (method local if you wish) variable and then assigning `nil` to that variable when you've done with the internal pointer. In the case of `static` be careful about concurrency!

In practice your code will probably work in both GC and ARC, probably more likely in ARC, but either could conceivably bite you especially as compilers change. For the cost of one variable declaration and one extra assignment you avoid the problem, cheap insurance.

[See [this](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/296-arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/) discussion as an example of short lifetime under ARC.]

Comment: Thanks, that Nerd Ranch discussion helped.  So #1. There IS a problem.  #2. There are 3 suggested ways to fix it: (a) your ivar suggestion (b) the objc_precise_lifetime qualifier (c) calling [someData self] gratuituously at the end of the function.  Your ivar suggestion is probably the easiest from the standpoint of clarity and maintenance.

Comment: My answer below discusses Apple's recent method of dealing with interior pointers.  Cheers and upvote if you like it.

Answer (score 3):

Under actual, real garbage collection that code is potentially a problem. Objects may be released as soon as there is no longer any reference to them and the compiler may discard the reference at any time if you never use it again. For optimisation purposes scope is just a way of putting an upper limit on that sort of thing, not a way of dictating it absolutely.

You can use `NSAllocateCollectable` to attach lifecycle calculation to C primitive pointers, though it's messy and slightly convoluted.

Garbage collection was never implemented in iOS and is now deprecated on the Mac (as referenced at the very bottom of [this FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17)), in both cases in favour of automatic reference counting (ARC). ARC adds `retain`s and `releases` where it can see that they're implicitly needed. Sadly it can perform some neat tricks that weren't previously possible, such as retrieving objects from the autorelease pool if they've been used as return results. So that has the same net effect as the garbage collection approach — the object may be released at any point after the final reference to it vanishes.

A workaround would be to create a class like:

```
@interface PFDoNothing

+ (void)doNothingWith:(id)object;

@end
```

Which is implemented to do nothing. Post your autoreleased object to it after you've finished using the internal memory. Objective-C's dynamic dispatch means that it isn't safe for the compiler to optimise the call away — it has no way of knowing you (or the KVO mechanisms or whatever other actor) haven't done something like a method swizzle at runtime.

EDIT: `NSData` being a special case because it offers direct C-level access to object-held memory, it's not difficult to find explicit discussions of the GC situation at least. See [this thread on Cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/199325-accessing-buffers-in-nsdata-nsmutabledata-under-garbage-collection.html) for a pretty good one though the same caveat as above applies, i.e. garbage collection is deprecated and automatic reference counting acts differently.

Comment: I've done some digging around, and re: "Assuming no manual pool management and everything else being normal, your [NSMutableData dataWithLength:123] will definitely last as long as the current method under ARC", other sources seem to disagree, including the discussion referred to by @CRD above and also here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html.  "...local variables of automatic storage duration do not have precise lifetime semantics."

Comment: @Merk I think you're quite right and my previous answer was quite wrong. I've therefore edited it so that the error doesn't persist. Apologies to all.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a generic answer that does not necessarily reflect Objective-C GC support. However, various GC implementaitons, including ref-counting, can be thought of in terms of Reachability, quirks aside.

---

In a GC language, *an object is guaranteed to exist as long as it is [Strongly-**Reachable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability)*; the "roots" of these Strong-Reachability graphs can vary by language and executing environment. The exact meaning of "Strongly" also varies, but generally means that the edges are Strong-References. (In a manual ref-counting scenario each edge can be thought of as an unmatched "retain" from a given "owner".)

C# on the CLR/.NET is one such implementation where *a variable can remain in scope and yet not function as a "root" for a reachability-graph*. See the [`Systems.Timer.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class and look for `GC.KeepAlive`:

> If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring [on the timer object] before the method ends.